# Concatenate 2 or more gif files with ffmpeg android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

Well, I have spent a great deal of time to find a way of combine gif files using ffmpeg library.But none of them seems to work for me.

What I have tried (I have used [ffmpeg android java library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)):

```
    String gif1=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/gif1.gif";
    String gif2=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/gif2.gif";

    String commandStr="-i concat:"+gif1+"|"+gif2+" -c copy "+file.getAbsolutePath()+"/output.gif";

    String[]command=commandStr.split(" ");
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
             //   Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Progress: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Progress TAG: ",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Failed: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Failure TAG: ",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Success: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Success TAG: ",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
```

But above command gives an error like this.

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                          built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                          configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                          libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                          libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                          libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                          libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                          libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                          libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                          libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                          libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                        Input #0, gif, from 'concat:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/gif1.gif|/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/gif2.gif':
                                                                          Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
                                                                            Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 500x500, 1.70 fps, 10 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
                                                                        Assertion video_enc->pix_fmt == AV_PIX_FMT_PAL8 failed at libavformat/gif.c:130
```

Can anyone please suggest me an efficient command to do this.

P.S: I have a dynamic file list so can't use the demuxing method which uses a text file.

Comment: You are encountering bug [#6640: Assertion failed when stream copying gif](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6640). For now, one workaround is to omit `-c copy`.

Comment: Thanx man...you save the day..please add this as an answer and i'll make it the acceptable one..and I have another small favor without reducing the resolution do you know any command to reduce the size of output gif..

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have used your method and but for some wierd reason it only concat first 2 gifs.I have given 4 gif files and it only did first 2.Is it another bug..please help me i dont have much knowledge in this library